# How can I use Jackson to bind Map<String, String[]> parameters to a bean?

Tags: java, jackson

I'd like to use Jackson to bind a `Map<String, String>` to a bean. The pitfall here is that the not all the fields are collections so it doesn't work.

I would need to tweak the ObjectMapper to only bind collections when the corresponding bean property is a collection.

```
public class MapperTest {

    public static class Person {
        public String fname;
        public Double age;
        public List<String> other;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String[]> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("fname", new String[] {"mridang"});
        props.put("age", new String[] {"1"});
        props.put("other", new String[] {"one", "two"});
        mapper.convertValue(props, Person.class);
    }
}
```

The above example doesn't work as Jackson expects all the fields to be collections.

---

I cannot change the Map structure as this is a legacy system I'm dealing with so I'm pretty much stuck with `Map<String, String[]>`

Comment: You are providing collections so why would Jackson expect otherwise?

Comment: A bit of a backstory here. I'm on a legacy web framework here that exposes all the URL query params as that hackish map. I'd like to migrate to a standardized ser-deser library and that seems to be my only way out.

Comment: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY Thats close, but you need the other way around ;)

Comment: I cannot check that, but you can try `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.Array)` on non array fields. Maybeit will work on deserialization as well.

Comment: @Antoniossss `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` won't word here. However `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS` does. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51438473/1426227).

Comment: Great, I didnt know that exists and managed to find that only so I was on good track;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS), as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS);

Map<String, String[]> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("fname", new String[] {"mridang"});
props.put("age", new String[] {"1"});
props.put("other", new String[] {"one", "two"});

Person person = mapper.convertValue(props, Person.class);
```